# Visual Flow Do a fast Lookup against a collection

Tags: flow, visual-workflow

Is it possible to do a fast lookup against a collection?

I need to get a list of email addresses based on a (changing) list of roles but Can't find a way to do a fast lookup and have a collection as a filter:

ListemailList = [SELECT EMAIL FROM Contact WHERE Account =:accountID AND Role__c IN :roleList];

where role list would be prepopulated with a list of roles defined by my flow logic.

Is it possible within a flow or should I just go the invocable method way?

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not possible to filter this way in flows, only apex.